# Can I get the Hamiltonian in the Heisenberg picture by simply plugging in the position and momentum in the Heisenberg picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am learning the relationship between Schrödinger and Heisenberg pictures. I have a question about how to compute the time-dependent Hamiltonian with the form
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x,t)$$
in the Heisenberg picture.

To define notation clearly, I use $H_H(t),p_H(t),x_H(t)$ to denote quantities in the Heisenberg picture, while I use $H,p,x$ to denote the quantities in the Schrödinger picture.

By definition
$$ H_H(t)=U^\dagger(t)H U(t).$$
My question is whether a straightforward plugin also gives the correct answer, that is
$$ H_H(t)= \frac{p_{H}^2(t)}{2m} + V(x_H(t),t).$$

Comment: A complete answer to your question is "yes", which means it is not exactly a good question for this site's model. Nevertheless, I think it is a good question, although it might require some editing to make it more suitable to the site. Would you mind taking a look at [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13109/168783) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6669/168783) meta posts to see how your question could be improved?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and suggestion! I changed my question according to the suggestion in one post you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is it is correct if assuming $V$ is smooth enough to do a Taylor series. My calculation is
$$
U^\dagger(t)p^2 U(t) = U^\dagger(t)p U(t)  U^\dagger(t)  p U(t) =p_{H}^2(t) 
$$
and
$$ U^\dagger(t)V(x,t) U(t) =U^\dagger(t) \left ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{V^{(n)}(0,t)}{n!}x^n \right ) U(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{V^{(n)}(0,t)}{n!} x^n_H(t)=V(x_H(t),t),
$$
where $V^{(n)}(0,t)$ is the $n$-th partial derivative.